# Comparing numbers Get different result

Tags: c#, comparable

I am sure that there is a simple explanation but cannot work out the following:

```
     const short amount = 30000;
     bool isGreater =
             ComparableExtensions.IsGreaterThan(amount, 29000); //returns true

     bool isGreaterThan2 = 
     amount.IsGreaterThan<short>(29000);//returns false

      public static class ComparableExtensions
      {
            public static bool IsGreaterThan<T>(this T leftValue, T rightValue) 
            where T : struct, IComparable<T>
            {
                var result = leftValue.CompareTo(rightValue) == 1;
                return result;
            }

      }
```

Is it because i put a "Struct" contraint?

any explanation or suggestions?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, your mistake using `leftValue.CompareTo(rightValue) == 1`.

Instead, say `leftValue.CompareTo(rightValue) > 0`.

All you know is that `CompareTo` returns `< 0` if `leftValue` is less than `rightValue`, `0` if `leftValue` equals `rightValue` and `> 0` if `leftValue` is greater than `rightValue`. You can not only check for equality with `1`.

Additionally, the reason that you see different behavior between the two calls is because in the first case you are calling `IsGreaterThan<int>` because the literal constant `29000` will be interpreted as `Int32`, but in the second case you explicitly say `short` so it will be interpreted as `Int16`.

Comment: That's right but if that's the case it should produce the same result for both calling the extension method directly or as a method of left value

Comment: @Beatles1692: No. In the first case `Int32` is used as `T` because the literal `29000` is interpreted as `Int32`, in the second case `Int16` is used at `T` because he explicitly said so. `CompareTo` behaves differently for the two types.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation for `IComparable`, and the return value of the `CompareTo` method. It states that it will return a value less than zero if `a < b`, exactly zero if `a == b`, and a value greater than zero if `a > b`. Yet you are comparing the return value to `1`. There is no guarantee this method will ever return `1`. You should instead do:

```
var result = leftValue.CompareTo(rightValue) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The current `short.CompareTo()` implementation is something like this:

```
public int CompareTo(short value)
{
    return (int)(this - value);
}
```

while the `int.CompareTo()` implementation is something like this:

```
public int CompareTo(int value)
{
    if (this < value)
    {
       return -1;
    }
    if (this > value)
    {
       return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the first case the generic `T` type is inferred as `Int32` because `29000` is an `Int32` string literal and so the `int.CompareTo()` method is called.

In the second case you're specifically saying that `T` is `short` and then the `short.CompareTo()` is called.

As other answers already pointed out, `IComparable<T>` specification doesn't assure to return always:

```
 0 : if the numbers are equal  
-1 : if the number is lower than the other
 1 : if the number is greater than the other
```

but just says that it must return:

```
0            : if the numbers are equal  
a number < 0 : if the number is lower than the other
a number > 0 : if the number is greater than the other
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler infers the generic type in the first (static) call. It uses `Int32`. The `Int32.CompareTo` method returns 1 for greater than.

In the second, your call from an `Int16` forces `T` to be `Int16`. `Int16.CompareTo` returns the actual difference between the two values*. Legal under `IComparable` (which only requires a value > 0) - but different enough for your call to fail.

Explicitly casting the first call to `short` will cause it to fail as well.

`*` No, I have no idea why Int16 is implemented that way. Seems to be "because it can be"(`Byte` behaves the same) - since you can subtract without fear of overflow (since you're casting to a wider type for the result). It'd require more work to do something similar for `Int32` which I suppose wasn't worth the effort.